# What is the difference between dataset and database?

Tags: database, dataset

What is the difference between a dataset and a database ? If they are different then how ?

Why is huge data difficult to be manageusing databases today?!

Please answer independent of any programming language.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In American English, *database* usually means "an organized collection of data". A database is usually under the control of a database management system, which is software that, among other things, manages multi-user access to the database. (Usually, but not necessarily. Some simple databases are just text files processed with interpreted languages like awk and Python.)

In the SQL world, which is what I'm most familiar with, a database includes things like tables, views, stored procedures, triggers, permissions, and data.

Again, in American English, *dataset* usually refers to data selected and arranged in rows and columns for processing by statistical software.  The data might have come from a database, but it might not.

Comment: So, if my data are images, not numbers, can I use *dataset* also?

Comment: @Sigur: I would call images arranged for processing by statistical or AI software a dataset.

Answer (score 7):

## Database

The definition of the two terms is not always clear. In general a **database** is a set of data organized and accessible using a **database management system (DBMS)**. Databases usually, but not always, are composed of several **tables** linked together often accessed, modified and updated by various users often simultaneously.

[Cambridge dictionary:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/database)

> A structured set of data held in a computer, especially one that is
> accessible in various ways.

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/database)

> a usually large collection of data organized especially for rapid
> search and retrieval (as by a computer)

## Data set (or dataset)

A **data set** sometimes refer to the contents of a **single database table**, but this is quite a restrictive definition. In general, as the name suggests, is a set (or collection) of data hence there are datasets of images like [Caltech-256 Object Category Dataset](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/7694/) or videos e.g. [A large-scale benchmark dataset for event recognition in surveillance video](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5995586). A data set purpose is usually designed for the analysis rather to a continual update form different users, hence represent the end of a collection of data or a snapshot of a specific time.

[Oxford dictionary:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/data_set)

> A collection of related sets of information that is composed of
> separate elements but can be manipulated as a unit by a computer.
>
> ‘all hospitals must provide a standard data set of each patient's
> details’

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dataset)

> a collection of separate sets of information that is treated as a
> single unit by a computer

Answer (score 5):

A dataset is the data... usually in a table or can be XML or other types of data however it's only data... it doesn't really do anything.

And as you know a database is a container for the dataset usually with built in infrastructure around it to interact with it.

Huge data isn't hard to manage for what I do.  I guess you're asking a study related question?

Answer (score 2):

Dataset is just a set of data (maybe related to someone and may not be for others ) whereas Database is a software/hardware component that organizes and stores data or dataset. Both are different things practically.

Huge data needs more infrastructure and components (hardware & software) or computing power & storage for efficient storage or retrieval of data's . More huge data means more components hence difficult. Modern days database provides good infrastructure to handle huge data's processing (both read/write) , check datalake management by Microsoft which manages relational data or dataset extensively.

Comment: Please be explicit about what you mean by h/w and s/w.

Comment: Yes h/w means - hardware , s/w means software . Sorry for the confusions , I have just corrected it .